# Randomly selecting single point from within multiple fishnet grid-squares?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select, random, subset

Using ArcGIS, I have a large data set of occurrence data many of which are in similar places. I have created a fishnet around the total area and want to select a single random point from within each grid-square of the fishnet.

How do I go about this?

I want to run this multiple times so that I can then bootstrap it. I know I could subset each individual grid-square but there are approximately 100 of them so this would take a very long time.

Comment: Which ArcGIS version do you use?

Comment: @BERA I am using ArcMap 10.5.1

Answer (score 3):

You can use arcpy to randomly select points by some group attribute. In your case fishnet id.

First [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) Points with fishnet to get a fishnet id attribute on all Points.

Then modify the commented lines and execute this in the Python window with the point layer added to the map:

```py
import arcpy, random
from collections import defaultdict

points = 'points' #Layer name
groupfield = 'fishnet_id' #Some id identifying each fishnet cell
sample_size = 1 #Points to select per group

oidfield = arcpy.Describe(points).OIDFieldName

groups = defaultdict(list)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, [groupfield, oidfield]) as cursor:
    for key,value in cursor:
        groups[key].append(value)

oidlist = []
for key,value in groups.iteritems(): # use groups.items() for ArcGIS Pro/py3
    oidlist.extend(random.sample(value,sample_size))

sql = """{0} IN({1})""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(points,oidfield), ','.join([str(i) for i in oidlist]))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(points, where_clause=sql)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without the use of arcpy?

Comment: @BillyGardener probably, for example with ModelBuilder. But why not arcpy?

Comment: Not much experience using arcpy, I'm still trying to get with the basics of using it.

Comment: Ok! But my answer should not need much changing, only point layer name and group/fishnet field. I would recommend learning the da.Search/UpdateCursors. I use them Daily.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to implement the above. I have a raster layer (tiff) in 10m resolution and a lidar layer of several millions of point (about 200 points in each 10 m grid of my raster layer). How do I create a new point shapefile of the samples from my lidar point. Also, how can I manipulate my new point file such that it will give me 1 sample (mean value of all points in the 10 m grid) from each 10 m grid?

Comment: @user18058 you need to convert raster to polygons and lidar data to points. Then intersect points with polygons to get a polygon ID attribute to each point then adapt the code and run